# What is the null argument to cb in multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

In the code below, from the multer API, the two cb functions take null as their first argument. What is the significance of null and what other values might be used here other than null?

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }
```

Comment: Normally when using callbacks it's a common practice to make the first argument of a callback an error state.   eg. `callback(new Error("oops something went wrong"));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asynchronous functions which take a callback often format the callback such that the first argument provided to the callback is the error, if any error is encountered, while the second argument is the successful retrieved value (if no error is encountered). That's exactly what's happening here. If `destination` or `filename` involved something which might throw an error, then the first argument you pass to `cb` could be the error, for example:

```
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
  if (!authorized) {
    cb(new Error('You are not authorized to do this!'));
    return;
  }
  cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
}
```

The reasoning is, if the first argument is the error, the module that passes `cb` is incentivized to use and examine the first argument, allowing for proper error handling.

If the error was passed as the *second* argument, for example, it would be easy for lazy programmers to simply ignore it, and define the callback such that it only looks at the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is the error-first callback pattern established in the early days of Node.JS core and libraries developed in its ecosystem. It is still a common pattern, but mostly subsumed by things like promises or async/await. Here is the relevant section from the Node.JS docs https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_first_callbacks.

The other option other than `null` would be an instance of some type of `Error`.

Answer (score 1):

The `null` means there was no error and you are calling the callback with a successful completion and a resulting value.

The node.js asynchronous callback convention is for a callback that takes two parameters that would look like this if it was a declared function:

```
function someCallbackFunction(err, value) {
    if (err) {
        // process err here
    } else {
        // no error, process value here
    }
}
```

The first parameter is an error (`null` if no error, usually an instance of `Error` object if there is an error).  The second is a value (if there was no error).

So, you pass `null` as the first argument when there is no error and the second argument will contain your value.

FYI, there is [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_first_callbacks) for this callback style.